# Problems in paginate_links with custom query loop and MB-Relationships

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

Im having some troubles with paginate_links.
Im using the plugin MB-Relationships, and 2 custom-post-types: Artist and Artworks.

On the `single-artist` I need to do a Query to show all the artworks related to that Artists. This is working well, but the paginate_links seens a little bit odd. I´ve oppened an issue on Mb-relationships github page: https://github.com/wpmetabox/mb-relationships/issues/21#issuecomment-466878189 and tried to use `page` instead of `paged`

This is my paginate_links configuration:

```
$pages = paginate_links([
        //'base' => str_replace(999999999, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link(999999999))),
        'format' => '?page=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('page')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'type' => 'array',
        'show_all' => false,
        'end_size' => 2,
        'mid_size' => 1,
        'prev_next' => true,
        'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
        'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
        'add_args' => false,
        'add_fragment' => '',
    ]
    );
    var_dump($pages);
```

The `var_dump` echoes this:

```
/app/public/wp-content/themes/wiki-ema-template/inc/numeric-pagination/wp-bootstrap4.1-pagination.php:47:
array (size=8)
0 => string '<a class="prev page-numbers" href="http://wiki-ema.local/wiki-ema/autor/autor-desconhecido/2/">&laquo;</a>' (length=106)
  1 => string '<a class='page-numbers' href='http://wiki-ema.local/wiki-ema/autor/autor-desconhecido/2/'>1</a>' (length=95)
  2 => string '<span aria-current='page' class='page-numbers current'>2</span>' (length=63)
  3 => string '<a class='page-numbers' href='http://wiki-ema.local/wiki-ema/autor/autor-desconhecido/2/?page=3'>3</a>' (length=102)
  4 => string '<span class="page-numbers dots">&hellip;</span>' (length=47)
  5 => string '<a class='page-numbers' href='http://wiki-ema.local/wiki-ema/autor/autor-desconhecido/2/?page=82'>82</a>' (length=104)
  6 => string '<a class='page-numbers' href='http://wiki-ema.local/wiki-ema/autor/autor-desconhecido/2/?page=83'>83</a>' (length=104)
  7 => string '<a class="next page-numbers" href="http://wiki-ema.local/wiki-ema/autor/autor-desconhecido/2/?page=3">&raquo;</a>' (length=113)
```

The problem resides on the `number 1` link that gives me a URL without the `/?page=1`, this link, when clicked, reload the same page.

When I uncomment the `'base'` configuration it gives me the URL with the `page/%_%` that sends me to a 404 page.

All the other number are working just fine. Only the link to `number 1` page is not working.

Could someone give me a light on that?

Thank you!

Comment: It's normal for the page 1's URL to have no `?page=1` since with or without that both bring you to the same page.

Comment: @SallyCJ but lets suppose I have 83 pages in that pagination.
when im on `page 83` the number 1 page link have no parameter.
`1 => string '<a class='page-numbers' href='http://wiki-ema.local/wiki-ema/autor/autor-desconhecido/83/'>1</a>'  2 => string '<a class='page-numbers' href='http://wiki-ema.local/wiki-ema/autor/autor-desconhecido/83/?page=2'>2</a>'`

Comment: That *is* the expected behavior. `example.com/sample-page/` and `example.com/sample-page/?page=1` both show the same page (the first page), so WordPress doesn't add the `?page=1` to the page 1's URL.

Comment: @SallyCJ ok, i understand. But im getting the 1 URL like: `example.com/picasso/83` that only reload the 83 page. How can I clean the URL, removing the `/83` and get only the `example.com/picasso` ?

Comment: For single posts, using `'base' => get_permalink() . '%_%'` with `'format' => '?page=%#%'` would work.

Comment: thank you @SallyCJ! It´s working now, you were very helpful!